# Characterization of pretty compact spaces

Tags: gn.general-topology, compactness, compactifications, stone-cech-compactification

This is a cross post from [MSE](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4004859/characterization-of-pretty-compact-spaces).

I believe that the following problem have already been considered by some sophisticated topologist.

**Definition 1.** A non-compact Hausdorff topological space $X$ is called *almost compact* if its Stone–Čech compactification coincides with its one point compactification.

An example of almost compact space is $[0,\omega_1)$ for the first uncountable ordinal $\omega_1$.  All almost compact spaces are locally compact and pseudocompact.

**Definition 2.** A compact Hausdorff space $X$ is called *pretty compact* if $X\setminus\{p\}$ is almost compact for all non-isolated points $p\in X$.

I know that Stonean spaces are pretty compact. By a result of van Douwen, Kunen and van Mill ([There can be $C^*$-embedded dense proper subspaces in $\beta\omega - \omega$](https://staff.fnwi.uva.nl/j.vanmill/papers/papers1989/canbe.pdf)) $\beta\mathbb{N}\setminus \mathbb{N}$ is consistently pretty compact. What are other examples of pretty compact spaces? Does there exist any characterization of pretty compact spaces or at least a strong necessary condition?

Comment: From the discussion at MSE, I think I'm not alone in finding the terminology very distracting. For example (let's see if I've got this straight) $\mathbb R$ is not almost compact, so $S^1$ is not pretty compact, so compact does not imply pretty compact. But I think the terminology strongly suggests it should. Already, the fact that $\mathbb R$ is not almost compact makes the terminology feel wrong to me.

Comment: @TimCampion It's nevertheless pretty standard and already used by Gillman and Jerrison (almost compact I mean). Pretty compact is indeed a bit weird. That $\Bbb R$ feels almost compact is due to its completeness/connectedness  and linear structure, I think: in a connected ordered space we can always compactfity with at most two points.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A partial answer: other examples of pretty compact spaces are uncountable powers of $\{0,1\}$ and $[0,1]$, and in general products of uncountably many non-trivial compact Hausdorff spaces. See Problem 3.12.24(c) in Engelking's *General Topology*, or [Glicksberg, *Stone-Čech compactifications of products*](https://doi.org/10.1090/S0002-9947-1959-0105667-4). If $a$ is in the product take $b$ in the product that differs everywhere from $a$. Then $\Sigma(b)$ is a subset of $X\setminus\{a\}$. As the product is $\beta\Sigma(b)$ it is also $\beta(X\setminus\{a\})$ (general result: if $X\subseteq Y\subseteq\beta X$ then $\beta X=\beta Y$).

As noted in the question extremally disconnected compact spaces have the same property; as these are quite different from product spaces finding a characterization that is not a direct translation seems difficult.

Comment: Problem 3.12.24(c) in Engelking's General Topology states that the Cartesian product $X$ of compact Hausdorff spaces $\{X_s:s\in S\}$ is the Stone-Cech compactification of their $\Sigma$ product. By 2.7.14 from the same book the $\Sigma$ product of the family $\{X_s:s\in S\}$ is a set of the form $$\{x\in X: \operatorname{Card}(\{s\in S: x_s\neq a_s\})\leq \aleph_0 \}$$ for some $a\in X$. Clearly $\Sigma$ products are quite different from $X\setminus \{a\}$. So I don't think uncountable products of compact Hausdorff spaces are pretty compact. Am I right?

Comment: No, I added further explanation above.

Comment: Now it is clear. Thank you!